# Python error: TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
81     lst.append(str(r[f]).replace("\/", "/"))
82     #WRITE ROW WITH DATA IN LIST
83     outfp.write('\t'.join(lst).encode('utf-8') + "\n")
84     outfp.close()
```

I suspect the problem is on line 83. I have tried all to no avail.

Comment: You cannot add bytes (the result of `.encode()` call) to str `"\n"`. Just do `b"\n"`.

Comment: encode _after_ you've constructed the string so join, add whatever suffix and then encode.

Comment: @freakish that's fragile because a change to the encoding (or suffix) might break it. saner to just encode after you're done constructing your string instead of adding binary blobs to it.

Comment: I did what @freakish said, but it returned an error "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes"

Comment: If `write()` needs a `str`, why use `encode` in the first place? Simply remove it from your original code and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks @Krazor, removing the encode made my code works perfectly.